# MS Access Error: can't find the object 'autoexec.'

Tags: ms-access

I get this error when I open a ms access 2003 application on a user's windows 7. If I open the same application on my windows 7 machine I don't get the error.

Comment: Would it be possible to list the contents of your autoexec module to see if there is anything 'henky' in there?

Comment: I discovered that I didn't have an Autoexec macro so I created a blank one and it worked. However, users have been using the msaccess application without the Autoexec macro for quite a while and no problems. Why has this error popped up recently with a couple users and not all users at once? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a blank Autoexec solved the issue. I still don't know why it didn't affect all the users.